# Converting 6-digit Julian date to std date

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, date-conversion, julian-date

I have 6-digit Julian dates from DB table, and I am trying to convert them to std date. I get error as the format is not correct. `fmt = '%y%m%j'`

This is the function I have written:

```py
import datetime
def jdtodatestd (jdate):
    fmt = '%y%m%j'
    datestd = datetime.datetime.strptime(jdate, fmt).date()
    return(datestd)
x = jdtodatestd('122105')
print(x)
```

In above Julian date "122105":
1 is Century code
22 is Year
105 is 105th day of the year.

I am getting `2012-04-14` as result, but the expected result is `2022-04-15`.

Comment: As the first symbol, can you have different numbers instead of `1`? Can you give an example?

Comment: yes there will be two numbers, 0 and 1 represents the centuries.. you have to add 19 to the first digit.. If it is 0+19 then it will be from 19th century like 1993, 1998.... Like wise if it is 1+19 then it will 20th century like 2001, 2020 etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `jdate = str(19 + int(jdate[0])) + jdate[1:]` into your Python function and change format to `%Y%j`

```py
import datetime
def jdtodatestd (jdate):
    jdate = str(19 + int(jdate[0])) + jdate[1:]
    fmt = '%Y%j'
    datestd = datetime.datetime.strptime(jdate, fmt).date()
    return(datestd)
x = jdtodatestd('122105')

print(x)
# 2022-04-15
```